# Мусор в строке из строк (при склеивании)

Tags: c, строки, указатели, память

Всем доброго времени
Пытаюсь склеить 5 строк типа `char *` и `const char *` через `strcat`. Код:

```
char *one, *two, *three;

one = "1";
two = "2";
/// ниже: прибавляем 12 т.к. "one_", "_two_" и "_three"
/// занимают 15 символов, +1 символ запаса
three = (char *)malloc((16 + strlen(one) + strlen(two)) * sizeof(char));
strcat(three, "one_"); 
strcat(three, one);
strcat(three, "_two_"); 
strcat(three, two);
strcat(three, "_three");
printf("%s\n", three);
```

В результате получаю

> TYone_1_two_2_three

При этом, первые два символа - мусор - могут быть совершенно любыми (зависимости между ними и кодом не выявил).
Куда копать, что чинить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Умножать на `sizeof(char)` не нужно :)
2. Не `strcat(three, "one_")`, а `strcpy(three, "one_")`. В three после `malloc()` содержится мусор, это только `calloc()` обнуляет выделенную память (но и в этом случае всё равно логичней начинать со `strcpy`).
3. Magic numbers в коде - это всегда очень плохо. Понятно, что код похож на одноразовый пробник и тут ломать голову над правильным рассчётом памяти не хочется, но всё-таки...

Comment: WOW
А оно и правда работает =D
На самом деле, это просто упрощенный пример реального кода, где память выделяется посредством выверенных формул из strlen =) Поэтому никаких магических чисел нет, но замечание таки-дельное)